# FooTable Version 3, Add Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, footable

I am moving from version 2 of Footable to version 3. In version 2, you could add a hyperlink (that would be caught) by using something like...
**Select**

However, in version 3 the link fails to fire - almost like it isn't there.

Any suggestions/help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You now have to specify the datatype as html for it to render tags.  For example `<th data-type="html">Links</th>`. This was added as of version 3.